# Apache server one IP one PORT different services based on url

Tags: linux, centos, apache2

I have one httpd server running on CentOS 7, it is listening to port 443.

I want to run two things from this server:

1. A normal website - https://example.com/normal/website.html
2. An API Endpoint running on Python (or similar language) - https://example.com/api/***

The 2nd part should redirect my request to Python API endpoint.

Please advise if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Use a [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) to proxy /api to your backend. 
Another option would be to use api.example.com and apache vhosts. Apache is perfectly capable of running multiple vhosts on the same IP.

Comment: Thanks Lain, let me try this, will get back to you